# Does pyflink have a max function or max_by function?

Tags: python, pyflink

- I can't find the corresponding function max or max_ by
  ** This is my message **

```
Java

public class TransformTest2_Rolling {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        String inputPath = "/Users/yinbaidong/个人学习/Flink_t/src/main/resources/wudu.txt";
        DataStream<String> DataSource = env.readTextFile(inputPath);
        DataStream<SensorReading> datastream = DataSource.map(line ->{
                String[] fields = line.split(",");
                return new SensorReading(fields[0],new Long(fields[1]),new Double(fields[2]));
        });

        //分组
        KeyedStream<SensorReading, Tuple> keyStream = datastream.keyBy("id");
        DataStream<SensorReading> out=keyStream.max("temperature");
        out.print();
        env.execute();

    }
}
```

Java result

```
5> SensorReading{id=sensor_1',timestamp=1547718199,temperature=35.8}
2> SensorReading{id=sensor_2',timestamp=1547718499,temperature=35.8}
2> SensorReading{id=sensor_2',timestamp=1547718499,temperature=36.8}
5> SensorReading{id=sensor_1',timestamp=1547718199,temperature=39.8}
2> SensorReading{id=sensor_2',timestamp=1547718499,temperature=36.8}
2> SensorReading{id=sensor_2',timestamp=1547718499,temperature=36.8}
5> SensorReading{id=sensor_1',timestamp=1547718199,temperature=41.8}
```

I want to do this in Python

```
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment, RuntimeExecutionMode


def f_map():
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    env.set_runtime_mode(RuntimeExecutionMode.STREAMING)
    env.set_parallelism(1)
    ds = env.read_text_file("/Users/yinbaidong/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/wudu.txt")
    new_ds = ds.map(lambda i: {"id": i.split(",")[0], "timestamp": i.split(",")[1], "temperature": i.split(",")[2]}).key_by(
        lambda i: i.get("id")).max("temperature")
    new_ds.print()
    env.execute()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f_map()
```

Python This is an error message

*
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/yinbaidong/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/Test/Rolling.py", line 15, in 
f_map()
File "/Users/yinbaidong/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/Test/Rolling.py", line 10, in f_map
lambda i: i.get("id")).max("temperature")
AttributeError: 'KeyedStream' object has no attribute 'max'

This is my test data wudu.txt

```
sensor_1,1547718199,35.8
sensor_2,1547718299,35.8
sensor_2,1547718399,34.8
sensor_2,1547718499,35.8
sensor_2,1547718599,36.8
sensor_1,1547718699,41.8
sensor_1,1547718799,39.8
```

help me

Comment: All of these relational operations on datastreams have been (soft) deprecated in favor of using Flink's relational APIs (the Table and SQL APIs). Perhaps this explains why they haven't been provided in Pyflink.